# What is the best way to handle two async calls that must both pass and make an "irreversible" change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am currently wondering about this issue, I have a team to which I want to add a user (so write a new user to the database for that team) and I also want to increase the amount of users that team needs to pay for (I use stripe subscriptions).

```
async handleNewUser(user, teamId){
  await addUserToTeamInDatabase(user, teamId)

  await incrementSubscriberQuantityInStripe(teamId)
}
```

The problem is, which one do I do first? I recently ran into an issue where users were being added but the subscriber count was not increasing. However, if I reverse them and increment first and then write to database and something goes wrong in this last part, the client pays more but does not get a new member added. One possible way of approaching this is with try catch:

```
handleNewUser(user, teamId) {
    let userAddedToDatabase = false
    let userAddedInStripe = false

    try {
      await addUserToTeamInDatabase(user, teamId)
      userAddedToDatabase = true
      await incrementSubscriberQuantityInStripe(teamId)
      userAddedToStripe = true
    } catch (error) {
      if (userAddedToDatabase && !userAddedInStripe) {
        await removeUserFromTeamInDatabase()
      }
    }
  }
```

So I'm writing the new user to the database and then making a call to the stripe API.
Is there a better way to approach this because it feels clumsy. Also, is there a pattern to address this problem or a name for it?

I'm using Firebase realtime database.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: count the number in the database (and handle async/await correctly as noted below by Andy).

Comment: `handleNewUser` won't work because it's not `async`.

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Many database have ways of doing transactions which group multiple operations together.

Comment: Unclear how `userAddedToDatabase && userAddedInStripe` become true

Comment: Please note: I'm not asking for advic on async/await... This is pseudo code. I'm asking about a general problem I'm having.

Comment: @NicholasTower There is only one transaction in this example right

Comment: Since it is Datatbase problem you should use "Trasaction" which will abort all data wrtting if one of your code has error.
search Trasaction this keyword with your database name.

Comment: I see you edited your post to mention firebase realtime database. Here's how the realtime database does transactions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions If you're also using firestore, here's the documentation for transactions in firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: @NicholasTower Thanks for the response! Forgive me for my ignorance but this is only one write to the database, how would a transaction help?

Comment: I thought you were writing two things to the database? Sorry, i must have misunderstood what you're doing with stripe.

Comment: @NicholasTower No it's a call to the stripe API and let them know that the subscription (that they manage) must be increased by one user.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to perform is a transaction. In databases a transaction is a group of operations that is successful if all of its operations are successful. If at least one operation fails, no changes are made (all the other operations are cancelled or rolled back).

And Realtime Database supports transactions! Check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, I'm only doing one write to the database. Incrementing the subscription count is something I'm doing with a call to the stripe API.

Answer (score 0):

If both operations would be in the same database you'd normally bundle them in a transaction and the DB will revert to initial state if one of them fails. In your case you have operations in different external systems (DB & Stripe) so you'll have to implement the transactional logic yourself.

You could simplify your example by checking where the error comes from in the catch clause. Then you can get rid of the flags. Something like this:

```js
handleNewUser(user, teamId) {
  try {
    await addUserToTeamInDatabase(user, teamId)
    await incrementSubscriberQuantityInStripe(teamId)
  } catch (error) {
    // If we fail to increment subscriber in Stripe,
    // cancel transaction by removing user from DB
    if (instanceof error StripeError) {
      await removeUserFromTeamInDatabase(user, teamId)
    }

    // Re-throw error upstream
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I use instanceof but you you change the conditional logic to fit your program.